# Angular + Яндекс.карты = неправильное положение карты

Tags: angularjs, yandex-maps-api

Мне достался на поддержку сайт на Ангуларе. Сразу скажу, что я в нём ни в зуб ногой. Возникла необходимость установить туда Яндекс.карты. Использовал две библиотеки раз github.com/tulov/angular-yandex-map и два catatron.com/angular-ymaps/ и на обеих получал один и тот же результат: карты смещены в верхний левый угол и изначально выставленный масштаб не работает. Центр карты также смещён в левый верхний угол. Однако карта реагирует на изменение размера окна и после него отображается нормально (помимо того факта что геокоординаты нормально работают только со второй бибилотекой).

[Собственно мой сайт](http://aevit.ru). Карты находятся на последнем слайде "контакты"

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = angular.module('yourName', ['ymaps']);

app.config(function(ymapsConfig) {
  ymapsConfig.fitMarkers = false;
});
```

отменит "автоматически подстраивать видимую область и масштаб карты, чтобы было видно все точки на карте."